# MessageBox after service call do not act right?

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, message

I got a winform application where I listen on the Application_ThreadException event. When this is thrown I will make a simple call to the service (that will log the exception) and when we are back on the client MessageBox.Show will be used. Like this :

```
this.GetMyClientService.LogException(new MyApp.DataContracts.FaultContracts.Generellt.GeneralFault(exceptionContainer));
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("test");
```

The problem is that as long as I do the service call the MessageBox.Show will not bring up the application form and then place itself on top of it? Instead the Messagebox will be shown alone. If I click on the application icon in the tray the messagebox will be shown, not the form?

If I instead remove the service call line(GetMyClientService.Log...), then the messagebox will bring up the form and then place itself ontop of it. It is not possible to just bring up the form(this is what I need).

Why is that? I seemse to be the same thread that runs the service call that also runs the MessageBox.Show method?

BestRegards

Edit1 :

If I change it to this :

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(LogException1), exceptionContainer);
//this.GetMyClientService.LogException(new MyApp.DataContracts.FaultContracts.Generellt.GeneralFault(exceptionContainer));

System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("test");
```

It will also work. But as soon as the main UI thread do the service call the messageBox will be off?

Answer (score 0):

Your UI thread is blocked when you make a service call. Try making an async service call.

Comment: My view of this is that the UI thread is the one making the serviceCall and for this it will be blocked. This is no problem, I can wait. But then after the UI thread have made the service call it should show the messagebox. This also happens, the problem is that the form and the messagebox do not work togehter like day do If the service call is skipped?